# QGIS - Continuous buffer image [Heat Map]

Tags: qgis, heat-map

Is it possible to have the representation like the one the heat-map like the figure below using QGIS?
The way seems to use buffer options, but I do not know how.
Does exist any plugin that helps?
I am using QGIS1.8 on windows 7

[image: power]

Comment: Giulio; the effect you are looking for is a raster operation (rather than vector) and is called a heat map. Try a search for QGIS and heat map and you will find lots of options.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for it. In web era the solution to a problem is to know the correct word of the problem, the solution is somewhere on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS has a HeatMap Plugin that will do you what you want. Find it under Plugins > Heatmap. There are some instructions here: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/07/tutorial-making-heatmaps-using-qgis-and.html

Answer (score 4):

Since Qgis 2.8 heatmap can be rendered on live without any plugin. See the doc http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog28/index.html?highlight=heatmap#feature-live-heatmap-renderer

Comment: See also a nice tutorial here : http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html

Answer (score 3):

HeatMap Plugin for QGIS 1.8 is available

**Heatmap Plugin**

> The Heatmap plugin allows to create a heatmap from a point vector map.
>   A heatmap is a raster map showing the density or magnitude of point
>   related information. From the result “hotspots” can easily be
>   identified. Activate the Heatmap plugin
>
> First this core plugin needs to be activated using the Plugin Manager
>   (see Section Loading a QGIS Core Plugin). After activation the heatmap
>   icon heatmap can be found in the Raster Toolbar.
>
> Select from menu View ‣ Toolbars ‣ Raster to activate the Raster
>   Toolbar when it is not yet activated.

[image]

http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html